# Aeson - How can I create a new type for [String, Int]?

Tags: haskell, aeson

I am parsing a JSON object using `aeson` package and when trying to parse one section of the response I receive the following error:

```
Illegal kind: [String, Int]
```

This is the part of the JSON that I am trying to parse:

```
"rows": [
    [
      "Lorem ipsum... ",
      1756
    ],
    [
      "Lorem ipsum... ",
      577
    ],
    [
      "Lorem ipsum... ",
      471
    ],
```

I have tried the following in order to parse the JSON:

```
data RollbarJobResults =
  RollbarJobResults
   { 
     errors :: Array [String, Int]
   }
  deriving (Show)
```

What is the correct way of defining a new type that could fit into the `[String, Int]` structure?

Comment: I think this should be `Array [(String, Int)]`, so wrap it in a 2-tuple.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Actually, `Array (String, Int)` should be enough.

Comment: @chi: ah yes, somehow I got confused with the `[...]`, you are right :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, I got the solution thanks to the comments :)

```
  data RollbarJobResults =
    RollbarJobResults
     { 
       errors :: [(String, Int)]
     }
    deriving (Show)
```